# why am I getting network error for my Django website?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, webserver

My django website was integrated with default SQLite DB. Yesterday, I tried migrating it to Postgres, however, due to some password issue, the migration failed. Then I tried to fall back to SQLite just by uncommenting the SQLite portion in settings.py. But it failed too. I guess I broke my Database. To fix the issue I used the below CLI command to delete everything in the SQLite:

```
python manage.py migrate my-app-name zero
```

Then I used makemigratons and then migrate. So, here everything seem to go smoothly. However, now I faced the connectivity issue with my website. Its not launching from web browser.

I don't know if I have messed my entire environment itself.

My website is hosted on AWS on Ubuntu server, it has gunicorn and nginx up and running. Initially I was receiving some below error:

```
A communication error occurred: The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests
```

I checked the journalctl logs, and I found something like below:

```
nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
```

To try to fix the issue I followed the web [link](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/heres-fix-nginx-error-failed-read-pid-file-linux/). But, it is not working. I am not sure if this has anything to do with my situation.

Going forward, I restarted my AWS instance, just to see if that has any positive effect. But now, I see

```
Hmmm… can't reach this page
```

on my web browser.

I tried looking into the nginx server logs, and it just has below three lines

```
2020/08/14 16:27:23 [alert] 3246#3246: *22 open socket #12 left in connection 5
2020/08/14 16:27:23 [alert] 3246#3246: *23 open socket #13 left in connection 6
2020/08/14 16:27:23 [alert] 3246#3246: aborting
```

Then I also checked syslog to see if it has some important information. I did notice something through `"tail -f"` real time logs, I see below:

```
S=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: 2020-08-15 04:20:43 INFO Backing off health check to every 600 seconds for 1800 seconds.
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: 2020-08-15 04:20:43 ERROR Health ping failed with error - EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: #011status code: 404, request id:
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: caused by: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: #011"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]:  <head>
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]:   <title>404 - Not Found</title>
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]:  </head>
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]:  <body>
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]:   <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]:  </body>
Aug 15 04:20:43 primarySNS amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[898]: </html>
```

After looking at the above, now I feel something happened to my AWS instance. But I am not sure what needs to be done.

Note: The website was up and running before I tried the unsuccessful DB migration.

Please help and let me know if more info is required.

Thank you,

curl error message:

```
    "curl: (7) Failed to connect to schoolnskill.com port 80: Connection timed out

curl localhost messages:
curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
```

Comment: The error says "no EC2 instance role found"? Have you deleted the role or not attached?

Comment: That is the Irony. I didn't do anything on my AWS dashboard except for restart my EC2 instance. Please could you suggest how and what could I check in AWS? I am not that well versed with it

Comment: Upon fruther reading, the instance is for your SSM agent. Its installed by default. If you don't use it, then its fine. If you ssh into the instance, can you `curl` your website from inside or start it?

Comment: I did as you said "curl schoolnskill.com". But nothing happens. after hitting "enter", it just remains there in the CLI, it doen't even returns to CLI. I had to ctrl + c.

Comment: After some time I see connection timeout error. updated the original post.
"

Comment: and `curl localhost`? Also can you check your instance's security group?

Comment: updated the "curl localhost" in original post. In the security group I updated the inbound/outbound rules with the current IP that (my IP). but nothing seem to help

Comment: So the website is running. If it timeouts from outside, this is likely a SG (security group) issue. Can you go to EC2 console, and check what are inbound rules for your SG?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219847/discussion-between-user3521180-and-marcin).

Comment: This thread could be concluded. I got what I wanted from this. I found that firewall was causing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the chat discussion.

The connection issue was caused by `ufw` **firewall** on the instance. The firewall was **blocking** in the incoming connections to port 80.

The temporary solution was disable `ufw` to enable connections and further work on the the application.